# How do I swap (reassign) the capacitative hardware keys MENU and BACK on a Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, hardware, buttons, samsung-galaxy-s-3-neo

I am on Cyanogenmod 12.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo.

I found various answers on how to reassign hardware keys on Android devices, but they were always specifically for other devices and did not explain the rationale behind them, so that I could apply them for my particular device, without a long series of time intensive trial and error with a lot of config file edits and rebooting inbetween.

Answer (score 2):

**Instructions:**

1. Requires root!

   - a) Under Cyanogenmod Root activation itself requires the developer menu: Settings > About > Tap "Build number" multiple times until a toast message tells you that the developer menu got activated.
   - b) Settings > Developer > Root access > Set to: `Apps & ADB`.
   - Remark: Apps alone should suffice too, but maybe you want to edit the config file via USB cable from your Desktop.
2. Modify `/system/usr/keylayout/sec_touchkey.kl` which requires root:

   - a) File Manager (ships with Cyanogenmod) > Settings > General > Access mode > Extended
   - b) Now open that file and exchange `139` with `158` and `158` with `139`.
   - c) Save. You will be prompted for root access. Permit it. You should get feedback that the file was saved. Close the app.
   - Remark: A lot of tutorials instruct to alter `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl`, which on the S3 Neo had no effect. The [official documentation](http://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files.html) makes clear why, it explicitely tells *"Do not modify the generic key layout!"* and gives applicable instructions for *"Capacitive Buttons"*.
3. Reboot. Test if your keys work as intended.

   - For security reasons disable root (See: 1b) if you don't have good reasons to keep it on.
   - To undo your modification restore the keycodes in `sec_touchkey.kl` as they were before (See: 2b).

Comment: it's `aries- keypad.kl` for samsung captivate i897.